# Python+Selenium+PhantomJS with proxy list

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

In my script i used this method for working PhantomJS with proxy:

```
service_args = [
    '--proxy=0.0.0.0:3128',
    '--proxy-type=http',
    ]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
```

Please tell me can I use a proxy list ? I need that script worked until the PhantomJS will pass through the all proxy in list?
And how to implement that at the idle proxy, he wrote a message and move to the next? For example put detain 20 seconds and if there is no response from the proxy to go further.

Thank you advance

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I faced with the same problem and didn't come up with anything better than to restart browser with different proxy.